# Name correction In US Visa

Tags: visas, usa

My name is:

> Akash Gaurav (first name only)

In my US visa it is:

> Gaurav (first name)
>   Akash (surname)

My name is Akash Gaurav with the surname blank in my Indian passport.

In my DS-160 my given name is FNU and Given Name is Akash Gaurav.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure the edit helped, but you originally wrote "in DS-160 First name : FNU and Given Name :AKASH GAURAV" while "given name" and "first name" mean nearly the same thing.  Did you mean to write "in DS-160 First name : FNU and Last Name :AKASH GAURAV" or something else?

Comment: @akash Gaurav So we're all on the same page: in English writing, the name first in order is called "first name" or "given name." The name second in order is called "surname" or "last name" or "family name." I think I understand that your first name is "Akash Gaurav," and that you do not have a last name. Is that correct?

Comment: @david : yes David, they did Given name : Gaurav and Surname is : Akash